Progress bar / seek for Gif
How can I seek playback time of a gif?
I'm trying to have a progress bar for gifs to pause/seek at specific gif's playback time.
I couldn't find any HTML DOM property/interface like videoElement.currentTime for gif.
I tried to use a gif as a video source but video dom api seems not accepting gif as source.
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://link/to/a-gif-image.gif">
</video>


Yes multiple answers on that question answer my question.
Thank you :)
